# php sprintf displaying wrong number

Tags: php, printf

I'm having a weird problem where PHP's `sprintf` seems to be changing some numbers. This doesn't happen all the time, just occasionally.

The following code:

```php
echo sprintf('%04d',$product['priceUSD']*100)."(".($product['priceUSD']*100).")";
```

generates the following output for a $19.99 product: `1998(1999)`

I can work around this, but I'd love to know why it is doing it, and if there's any method to the apparent madness.

Update:
It looks like it's happening when converting from float to int.  The following gives the same output:

```php
echo (int)($product['priceUSD']*100)."(".($product['priceUSD']*100).")";
```

Comment: What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo sprintf('%.2f',$product['priceUSD']*100)."(".sprintf('%.2f',$product['priceUSD']*100).")";
```

What number format are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

First off: `%d` is kinda like an `(int)` cast.

```
19.99 = 1.99899999999999984368059813278E1 = 0x4033FD70A3D70A3D
```

in IEEE 64 Bit.

if we multiply that in floating point with 100 we get `1998.99999999999984368059813278E1` casted to int is `1998`.

"19.99 is just one of those numbers..." (see @[Dragons Link](http://floating-point-gui.de/))
for exact results use bcmath extension:

```
echo sprintf('%4d', bcmul ($price,100));
```

Answer (score 0):

To stabilize your multiplication while facing floating point arithmetic problems, leverage [the `bcmul()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php) to multiply the two numbers.

Secondarily, I should mention that `printf()` will perform rounding, but `(int)` will not.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/loMY6))

```
$product['priceUSD'] = '19.99';
printf('%04d', bcmul($product['priceUSD'], 100));
```

Output:

```
1999
```